# Pass list to Section within RootElement c#

Tags: c#, ios, list, xamarin, sections

I am adding certain values to a section of RootElement like so:-

```
NavigationRoot = new RootElement("Menu"){ //Here we create the root of the elements
     new Section("Pages"){
      new StringElement ("Feed"),
      new StringElement ("Messages"),
      new StringElement ("Nearby"),
      new StringElement ("Events"),
      new StringElement ("Friends"),

     },
```

Right now, the StringElements are hard coded. I want to pass a List of strings which I fetch from an API call to the section. This list would be dynamic. How can I pass this list to create the section of items with the string values in the List?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this using Linq if you have an Array of strings :-

```
from page in myStringArray select new StringElement (page) as Element;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var section = new Section("Pages");

foreach(var s in MyListOfStrings) {
  section.Add(new StringElement(s));
}
```